# UIPicker Set Default Value and Update Components

Tags: swift

I have a UIPicker with two components. The values in the second component change based on the first components selection.

However, if I set the first component's value programatically, the second component does not update.

This code is contained within viewDidLoad():

```
UnitPicker.dataSource = self;
UnitPicker.delegate = self;
UnitPicker.selectRow(temporaryTask.quantityFormat.rawValue, inComponent: 0, animated: false);
UnitPicker.reloadAllComponents();

if (UnitPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1)
{
    UnitPicker.selectRow(temporaryTask.quantityUnit.rawValue, inComponent: 1, animated: false);
    UnitPicker.reloadComponent(1);
}
else if (UnitPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2)
{
    UnitPicker.selectRow(temporaryTask.quantityUnit.rawValue - 3, inComponent: 1, animated: false);
    UnitPicker.reloadComponent(1);
}
```

Here is one of the delegate functions:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    if (component == 0)
    {
        return units.count;
    }
    else if (component == 1)
    {
        if (pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1)
        {
            return weightTypes.count;
        }
        else if (pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2)
        {
            return timeTypes.count;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Expected result (when the user chooses the first component):

[image: Expected Result]

Actual result (when I set the first component in code):

[image: Actual Result]

Then if the user chooses "Weight" and then "Time", the second components are shown correctly.

For some reason it is only showing one row, which I think is because of the "return 1;" line.

Thanks in advance for any replies :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistaken the index of selectedRows

```
if (UnitPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1)
else if (UnitPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2)
```

should be

```
if (UnitPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0)
else if (UnitPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1)
```

Do this on the delegate as well.

Comment: Ah sorry, there are three options in the first component and the second and third (index 1 and 2) ones reveal data in the second component.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the code from viewDidLoad() to viewDidLayoutSubviews() fixed the problem :)